# How to use `exists.elim` in Lean?

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

This proof is a tactics-based version of the one in "Logic and Proof" by Avigad et al.

```
import data.nat.prime
open nat

theorem sqrt_two_irrational_V2 {a b : ℕ} (co : gcd a b = 1) : a^2 ≠ 2 * b^2 :=
begin
    intro h,
    have h1 : 2 ∣ a^2, by simp [h],
    have h2 : 2 ∣ a, from prime.dvd_of_dvd_pow prime_two h1,
    cases h2 with c aeq,
    have h3 : 2 * (2 * c^2) = 2 * b^2,
        by simp [eq.symm h, aeq];
            simp [nat.pow_succ, mul_comm, mul_assoc, mul_left_comm],
    have h4 : 2 * c^2 = b^2,
        from eq_of_mul_eq_mul_left dec_trivial h3,
    have h5 : 2 ∣ b^2,
        by simp [eq.symm h4],
    have hb : 2 ∣ b,
        from prime.dvd_of_dvd_pow prime_two h5,
    have h6 : 2 ∣ gcd a b, from dvd_gcd (exists.intro c aeq) hb,
    have habs : 2 ∣ (1:ℕ), by simp * at *,
    exact absurd habs dec_trivial, done
end
```

which works. I'm trying to work my way backwards in the Lean manual, because tactics mode is much more intuitive for me. When attempting the same without tactics, I have trouble with the `exists.elim` part, as all the examples in the Lean manual show how to use it only to get the final goal not an intermediary step. Can anyone help me fix this code? Could `let` or `match` also be used for the same purpose?

```
theorem sqrt_two_irrational_V1 {a b : ℕ} (co : gcd a b = 1) : a^2 ≠ 2 * b^2 :=
assume h : a^2 = 2 * b^2,
have 2 ∣ a^2,
    by simp [h],
have ha : 2 ∣ a,
    from prime.dvd_of_dvd_pow prime_two this,
-- this line below is wrong
exists.elim ha (assume c : ℕ, assume aeq : a = 2 * c), 
-- also tried "let" and "match"
--let ⟨c, aeq⟩ := ha,
-- match ha with ⟨(c : ℕ), (aeq : a = 2 * c)⟩,
have 2 * (2 * c^2) = 2 * b^2,
    by simp [eq.symm h, aeq]; 
       simp [nat.pow_succ, mul_comm, mul_assoc, mul_left_comm],
have 2 * c^2 = b^2,
    from eq_of_mul_eq_mul_left dec_trivial this,
have 2 ∣ b^2, 
    by simp [eq.symm this],
have hb : 2 ∣ b,
    from prime.dvd_of_dvd_pow prime_two this,
have 2 ∣ gcd a b,
    from dvd_gcd ha hb,
have habs : 2 ∣ (1:ℕ), 
    by simp * at *,
show false, from absurd habs dec_trivial
```

Comment: — If you think tactics are a lot more intuitive, are you aware of the natural number game? It introduces tactics from the start. See http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/xena/natural_number_game/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved one bracket to fix the proof. Usually when you use `exists.elim` the entire rest of the proof should be inside the brackets.

```
theorem sqrt_two_irrational_V1 {a b : ℕ} (co : gcd a b = 1) : a^2 ≠ 2 * b^2 :=
assume h : a^2 = 2 * b^2,
have 2 ∣ a^2,
    by simp [h],
have ha : 2 ∣ a,
    from prime.dvd_of_dvd_pow prime_two this,
-- this line below is wrong
exists.elim ha (assume c : ℕ, assume aeq : a = 2 * c, 
-- also tried "let" and "match"
--let ⟨c, aeq⟩ := ha,
-- match ha with ⟨(c : ℕ), (aeq : a = 2 * c)⟩,
have 2 * (2 * c^2) = 2 * b^2,
    by simp [eq.symm h, aeq]; 
       simp [nat.pow_succ, mul_comm, mul_assoc, mul_left_comm],
have 2 * c^2 = b^2,
    from eq_of_mul_eq_mul_left dec_trivial this,
have 2 ∣ b^2, 
    by simp [eq.symm this],
have hb : 2 ∣ b,
    from prime.dvd_of_dvd_pow prime_two this,
have 2 ∣ gcd a b,
    from dvd_gcd ha hb,
have habs : 2 ∣ (1:ℕ), 
    by simp * at *,
show false, from absurd habs dec_trivial)
```

I usually use `let` instead of `exists.elim`. The syntax is `let ⟨c, aeq⟩ := ha in ...` This actually causes an error in your current proof, this is due to a bug that means `let` introduces a hypothesis called `_let_match` into your context that causes an error if you use it. `simp * at *` uses it in your proof, but if you replace it with `by clear_aux_decl; simp * at *` the proof will work.

You could also write `match ha with | ⟨c, aeq⟩ :=` instead of `let ⟨c, aeq⟩ := ha in`, but this time you have to put `end` at the end of the proof. This will have the same bug as happens with `let` and the fix is the same.